# I accidently uninstalled my software manager Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: software-installation

The software for downloading and installing software is gone. I am new at this. But am pretty sure it is gone. What can I do?

Comment: Reinstall it with `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-software`.

Answer (score 1):

Simply open a terminal and enter this command:

```
sudo apt-get install software-center
```

You can open a terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl + Alt + T</kbd> or by opening the Dash, entering "Terminal" into it, and hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

This installs the Ubuntu Software Center which is what you were using before if you're on 14.04.

If you're on 16.04, enter

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-software
```

to get back what you used before. I would, however, if I were you, still enter the first command instead. The Ubuntu Software Center is slower than Ubuntu Software but Ubuntu Software has many bugs.

Note that when you send either of these commands, you will be prompted for your password. This is the password you entered when installing (if you didn't change it since) and the one you use to log into your machine (if you didn't enable automatic login). You will not see your password, stars, dots, or anything the command line when typing it in. Don't get confused by this, just type it in, and hit enter.

Comment: Excellent instructions. My software-center is now back up and functioning normally.

Comment: Thank you. If this answered your question, please click the checkmark on the left to mark this question solved.